# Array to tuple in julia

Tags: dictionary, tuples, julia

Newbie in julia, got quite confused.

Here is an array:

```
array=["a","b",1]
```

I define a dictionary

```
dict=Dict()
dict["a","b"]=1
```

I want to use 'array' to define the dict

```
dict2 = Dict()
dict2[array[1:2]]=1
```

but they are not the same,

```
julia> dict
Dict{Any,Any} with 1 entry:
  ("a","b") => 1

julia> dict2
Dict{Any,Any} with 1 entry:
  Any["a","b"] => 1
```

How can I use 'array' to generate 'dict' instead of 'dict2'? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the splat operator when doing assignment:

```
julia> dict = Dict()
Dict{Any,Any} with 0 entries

julia> dict[array[1:2]...] = 1
1

julia> dict
Dict{Any,Any} with 1 entry:
  ("a","b") => 1
```

---

Note: You can specify the types in your Dict, that way these types of errors are protected against:

```
dict = Dict{Tuple{String, String}, Int}()
```

Answer (score 6):

Julia interprets something like `dict["a", "b"] = 1` as `dict[("a", "b")] = 1`, that is a multidimensional key is interpreted as a tuple key.

The issue arises because the output of `array[1:2]` is not a tuple but an array. You can convert an array to a tuple with

```
tup = tuple(array[1:2]...)
```

Then you can

```
dict2 = Dict()
dict2[tup] = 1
```

Notice the use of the splat operator `...` that unpacks `array[1:2]` to create a 2-element tuple instead of the 1-element tuple (with its only element being a 2-element array) that is created when you don't use `...`.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia 1.6 the following code works:

```
array=["a","b",1]
tup = Tuple(array[1:2])
dict2 = Dict()
dict2[tup] = 1

julia> dict2
Dict{Any, Any} with 1 entry:
  ("a", "b") => 1
```

It is no longer necessary to go via the splat operator